# On Accessing the appium doctor icon, getting error : Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.13.1 ']

Tags: macos, selenium, webdriver, appium

On Accessing the appium doctor icon, getting error : `Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.13.1 ']`...I am using 
appium version :1.5.3, 
IOS version : 11.0 & 8

[image]

Xcode version : 9.1 
MAC version : OS 10.13.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to the latest Appium Desktop client. The old one wouldn't work on Sierra OS. You can find it here: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases